# Unable to add the license key

Tags: install4j

`The license key you have entered is invalid for this version of install4j` When i add license key from License information window of install4j by selecting `'Enter license key' -> 'Single or evaluation license'`

What are the reasons for failure ?

Comment: The reason is simply that the license key is invalid.

Comment: Same license key added on Linux machine successfully but not able to add the same license key on other machine giving error as invalid license key.

Comment: Be that as it may, the error message means that the entered license key is not valid. We're not going to solve this here, please contact support and include the key there.

Comment: This is my mistake, wrong key entered.